# TeamCity & SVN - update not check out

Tags: svn, teamcity, nant

I've configured TeamCity+NAnt(MSBuild)+SVN for continuous integration.

All works fine, except one thing - time to time - SVN makes a full source checkout, not an update - an action which takes too long from QA's point-of-view.

Is any hint or config on to set that TeamCity should perform only update, not checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is trivial:[TC knowledge base](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Clean+Checkout#CleanCheckout-sourcescache)